# Combining multiple DEMs into one file geodatabase

Tags: dem, file-geodatabase

I have multiple file geodatabases (approximately 240) each contain a DEM.  My issue is taking the DEM from each and putting it into a single file geodatabase without alot of mind numbing work.  Additionally the DEMs from each geodatabase is labeled DEM1.